# Select numbers with more than 4 decimal places

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008

I have a SQL table with one float column populated with values like these:

```
  1.4313
  3.35
  2.55467
  6.22456
  3.325
```

I need to select rows containing only values with more than 4 decimals. In this case, the select must return:

```
2.55467
6.22456
```

Ideas? Thanks!

This is what I have tried so far

```
select * 
from table 
where CAST(LATITUDE AS DECIMAL(10,5)) - LATITUDE = 0
```

Comment: @Kaf  I tried select * from table where CAST(LATITUDE AS DECIMAL(10,5)) - LATITUDE = 0 but I'm looking for alternatives. Surprisingly its not too much information about this select out there.

Comment: Get the decimal part using `charindex()` and `right()`/`substring()` functions and then check for the length of the string > 4

Answer (score 37, accepted):

```
DECLARE @tbl TABLE (val float)
INSERT INTO @tbl SELECT 1234.567
INSERT INTO @tbl SELECT 1234.5678
INSERT INTO @tbl SELECT -1234.5678
INSERT INTO @tbl SELECT 1234.56789

SELECT *
from @tbl
where (((val*10000) - CONVERT(INT,(val*10000))) <> 0)
```

Comment: Ghost, your select looks like works too, but returns some additional rows. MegaTron's select returns 2080 rows, your select 2186. Right now I'm checking which one its correct.

Comment: After a deep review, I found your answer its the correct. This is the only select statement who return the correct values.

Comment: NICE BUT, why is the ABS function needed here? `(((val*10000) - CONVERT(INT,val*10000)) <> 0)` works fine for me

Comment: @CMS You are correct. I had probably started it with a length comparison and realized the negative caused an extra character; the ABS is probably a carry over from that attempt.

Comment: FLOOR(val*10000) is a tad bit cleaner than CONVERT, but works just as well!

Answer (score 16):

Why cant we make it simple by this query:-

```
SELECT * FROM table WHERE val LIKE '%.____%'
```

This selects what we want

Comment: This solution does not work given the example data in my answer.

Answer (score 10):

Another solution also:

```
SELECT * from table
where (round(value,2) - round(value,4) <> 0)
```

Comment: Worked perfectly on MySQL - simples too!

Answer (score 8):

Given answers did not work for me with MaxDb, but this did:

```
where FLOOR(value * 10000) != value * 10000
```

[Source](https://www.itsupportguides.com/knowledge-base/server-side-tips/sql-query-find-numbers-with-more-than-two-decimal-places/)

Reduce/Increase 0`s for less/more precision.

Comment: Works for me on Oracle. Another way on Oracle is:
select to_char(value) from table where value != round(value,4);

Answer (score 6):

This works on Postgres 11:

```
SELECT * FROM mytable WHERE mycolumn != ROUND(mycolumn::numeric,2)
```

Answer (score 4):

http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/abadc/3/0

Seems like something like this should work...

all it does is convert the number to an integer to drop off decimals after multiplying it * 10 to power of decimals you need then it compares that int version of the number to the base number after it too was multiplied by 10 to the power of # of decimals.

If the numbers don't match, then you have decimals beyond 4.  If they do match, then it was 4 or fewer.

```
Select *
      from foo
      where cast(myNum*power(10,4) as int) <> myNum*power(10,4)
```

Comment: This answer makes the same results as Ghots' answer. Performance wise, looks like this select acts a little more faster.

Answer (score 2):

Please try something like:

```
select * from table
where RIGHT(CAST(value as DECIMAL(10,5)), value), 1) != 0
```

Comment: Glad to have been of help

Comment: @BernieSF & MegaTron It won't work if the value is 3.356009

Comment: @MegaTron just one note: worked for my in this form: RIGHT(CONVERT(DECIMAL(10,5), MyColumn), 1) != 0

Comment: I get an error when running this answer's where clause

Comment: @AnupAgrawal its right. If the number ends with a '9', don't meet the condition and its left out from the results.

Answer (score 2):

```
SELECT *
FROM table WHERE
(abs(val)*100000)%10 <> 0
```

Comment: Code only answers are bad - please elaborate what you did, how it works any why it solves this question - for ppl with less sql skills ;)

Answer (score 1):

It's an older question but it checks out.

```
select val
from table
where ((val * 100) % 1) > 0
```

Change 100 to your precision.

Answer (score 0):

You can multiply it with `10000` and subtract it from the original number replacing `.` with `''`.

[Fiddle](http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!6/200f4/1)

```
select * from tablename
where replace(numcolumn,'.','') - numcolumn * 10000 > 0
```

Comment: Doesn't work correctly. Returns rows with 3 decimals  :(

Comment: please try the modified version

Comment: I tried your new version. Looks like works, but mysteriously returns fewer rows!

Comment: what do you mean by `returns fewer rows`?

Comment: @MegaTron select returns 2080 rows, your select 984 rows

Answer (score 0):

Below is the Code that will check the precision for 4 decimal places:

1. Replace `MyNum`, with column you are checking for precision
2. Replace `MyTbl`, with the table you are using
3. Replace `4`, with whatever precision you are checking for

Sql:

```
SELECT  MyNum
      , LEN(CAST (MyNum AS CHAR))
      , -------1. length of decimal number, after conversion to CHAR
        CHARINDEX('.', CAST (MyNum AS CHAR))
      , ---2.length of numbers after the '.'
        LEN(CAST (MyNum AS CHAR)) - CHARINDEX('.', CAST (MyNum AS CHAR))  -----subtracting 1-2, to get the length of numbers after decimal point '.'
FROM    MyTbl
WHERE   LEN(CAST(MyNum AS CHAR)) - CHARINDEX('.', CAST(MyNum AS CHAR)) > 4; --checking if there are more than 4 numbers after the decimal point '.'
```

Answer (score 0):

1. Cast the number as text
2. Split the text using '.' as separator
3. Use the 2nd index and apply a length
4. Filter

```sql
--i.e. with postgreSQL.
--1)
select data_numeric, length(arr[2]) as str_length
from (
  select data_numeric, regexp_split_to_array(data_numeric::text, '\.') as arr from TABLE
) temp;

--2)
with t1 as (
  select data_numeric, regexp_split_to_array(data_numeric::text, '\.') as arr from TABLE
), t2 as (
  select data_numeric, arr[2] as decimals, length(arr[2]) as length from t1
)
select * from t2;
```

Answer (score 0):

Select numbers with more than 2 decimal places:

I had an example, where `((abs(val)*100)` and `CONVERT(INT,(abs(val)*100))` for value "2.32" in float type column returned two different values.

```
(abs(2.32)*100) = 232

CONVERT(INT,(abs(2.32)*100)) = 231
```

That caused wrong select query answers in case for comparing to 0.
I suppose that `MSSQL CONVERT()` function round numbers in such way that for some float number cases, posted solution would not work.

Here is how I did it for more than 2 decimal places:

```
DECLARE @tbl TABLE (val float)
INSERT INTO @tbl SELECT 2.32
INSERT INTO @tbl SELECT 1234.54
INSERT INTO @tbl SELECT 1234.545
INSERT INTO @tbl SELECT 1234.5456
INSERT INTO @tbl SELECT 1234.54567

select * from @tbl where abs(val-round((val),2)) > 0.001
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use the `scale` function, since postgresql 9.6.

```
select LATITUDE FROM TABLE where scale(LATITUDE) > 4;
```

If your data type is float you will get `SQL Error [42883]: ERROR: function scale(double precision) does not exist.` Below would fix it.

```
select LATITUDE FROM TABLE where scale(cast(LATITUDE as numeric)) > 4;
```

Answer (score 0):

This is the simplest solution, Use `WITH (NOLOCK)` if it's necessary in your case otherwise you can remove it. This will return the records having at least 4 decimal points in `ColumnName` table.

```
SELECT * FROM TableName WITH (NOLOCK) WHERE ColumnName LIKE '%.____'
```

[image]

Answer (score 0):

We have another solution like,

```
DECLARE @tbl TABLE (Balance FLOAT)

INSERT INTO @tbl VALUES (1.4313)
INSERT INTO @tbl VALUES (3.35)
INSERT INTO @tbl VALUES (2.55467)
INSERT INTO @tbl VALUES (6.22456)
INSERT INTO @tbl VALUES (3.325)
INSERT INTO @tbl VALUES (-4.1234567)

--More than 4 decimal places             
SELECT * FROM @tbl WHERE CAST(Balance AS DECIMAL(9, 4)) - Balance <> 0
```