# SQL Query to select 3 or 4 Decimal Point Values only

Tags: sql

Is there a way through an SQL query or similar to find values that exceed 2 decimal points?
Something like

```
SELECT * FROM TableName WHERE the decimels > 2
```

Example image below highlights 2 values are need to be fixed, but im not sure how to select these values only.

[image]

We only display 2 decimals on screens so anything over that is not rounded. We do fix them up as we see them but there are thousands of values in the Database. Being able to easily identify them would really help.

Thanks

Comment: Hint: `ROUND(1429,0) = 1429`, `ROUND(1453.33,0) <> 1453`.

Comment: For your reference : https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32462644/select-numbers-with-more-than-4-decimal-places

Comment: Please do not post images of code/errors/data. Instead post the code/errors/data as text in a code block. See [How do I ask a good question?](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask). People with screen readers cannot know what you mean, because they cannot see the content of the image.

Comment: [Why should I tag my DBMS](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/388759/)

Answer (score 0):

you can count decimals with `floor(log10(reverse(abs(Price)+1)))+1`:

```
select * from TableName
where floor(log10(reverse(abs(Price)+1)))+1 > 2;
```

here is a test with your numbers: [SQL Fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/9651f/2)
and [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14715141/how-do-i-count-decimal-places-in-sql) the reference for decimal count

Answer (score 0):

This function could be help you

`select REVERSE(ROUND(REVERSE(3.2300),1))`